# I am not getting the right output for dictionary and list in python

Tags: python, list

```py
roll_number = [47, 64, 69, 37, 76, 83, 95, 97]
sample_dict = {'Jhon':47, 'Emma':69, 'Kelly':76, 'Jason':97}
 
for a in roll_number:
    if a not in sample_dict.values():
        roll_number.remove(a)

print(roll_number)
```

My output is [47, 69, 76, 95, 97] instead of [47, 69, 76, 97]. Can someone please explain?

Comment: Why do you expect this output?

Comment: Just change this line - `for a in roll_number[::]:`  it should work.   Try to see why, run here - https://pythontutor.com/

Comment: @Divine Jojolola if you print out each iteration of 'a ' then there will be the following elements: 47,64,37,83,97. By removing 64 in the loop, you immediately jump to 37, eliminating 69. This works until you have two numbers in a row that don't match (83, 95).

Answer (score 1):

The issue I see is that you're **iterating** over the array **while removing items** from it. That leads to **unsafe removal**.

You could use a `set` to 'freeze' the array and **remove its values safely**:

```
roll_number = [47, 64, 69, 37, 76, 83, 95, 97]
sample_dict = {'Jhon':47, 'Emma':69, 'Kelly':76, 'Jason':97}

roll_set = set(roll_number)
for a in roll_number:
    if a not in sample_dict.values():
        roll_set.remove(a)

print(roll_set)
```

It'll print `{97, 69, 76, 47}`. If you want a list you can use `list(roll_set)`.

Althoug **set** is a **standard python type**, you could also use another temporary list and would have the same result.

Answer (score 1):

You are removing elements while iterating the list. (*Bad Idea*) Removing elements while iterating the list will affect the iterator.

As mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1207406/how-to-remove-items-from-a-list-while-iterating), there are several approaches:

- use a list comprehension to create a new list containing only the elements you don't want to remove
- create a copy of the original list
- by assigning to the slice `somelist[:]`, you can mutate the existing list to contain only the items you want
- use `itertools`
- iterate backwards

Answer (score 0):

I believe it happen because you remove a value from an array while you loop on the exist array, just copy the existing array and remove the values of the copy

```py
import copy

roll_number = [47, 64, 69, 37, 76, 83, 95, 97]
sample_dict = {'Jhon': 47, 'Emma': 69, 'Kelly': 76, 'Jason': 97}

roll_number_b = copy.deepcopy(roll_number)
for a in roll_number:
    if a not in sample_dict.values():
        roll_number_b.remove(a)

print(roll_number_b)

#output: [47, 69, 76, 97]
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use a list comprehension:

```
[x for x in roll_number if x in sample_dict.values()]

[47, 69, 76, 97]
```

You can see the example in this question:

[How to remove items from a list while iterating?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1207406/how-to-remove-items-from-a-list-while-iterating)

Answer (score 0):

It is because the `result` is being updated in the loop.

To understand the behavior of the code, consider this example:

```
>>> lst = [1, 2, 3]
>>> lst.pop(0)    
1
>>> lst.pop(1)
3
```

You can obtain the expected output with this code (using the `while` loop and only incrementing the loop counter when the element does not remove):

```
i = 0
while i < len(roll_number):
    if roll_number[i] not in sample_dict.values():
        roll_number.pop(i)
    else:
        i += 1
```

#### Output

The output with the above code and with the given input is:

```
[47, 69, 76, 97]
```